# How do I create a link (or button) that will execute an Application Helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

I am new to **ruby/rails** and trying to create links that will update a variable in session. I have the following method defined in `application_helper.rb--`I put it here in hopes that this is the correct place to have it so it can be used all all views:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def add_workspace_to_session(workspace_id)
    session[:workspace_id] = workspace_id 
  end

end
```

In the view I want to create a simple link (or button) that will call this helper, passing in a workspace ID so that it updates `session[:workspace_id]`. How do I make this link in the view? Using link_to? I'm missing something...having to do with routes?

Thanks!

Comment: View helpers are there to offload logic out of your view files, they don't respond to actions. You're going to want to create a controller action that does what you want, wire it up in routes and link_to that

Comment: You have to update `session` in your **controller**. Helpers are for **view**.

Comment: DVG, thanks I ended up doing what you said and making this method a controller action and then adding a route to it

Comment: @DVG I'd like to give you points for this since i ended up using your solution. can you re-post as an answer? or perhaps i'm missing some way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating a button or link it should be pointed to a url path not just a helper method. A quick fix for this is add a path to the helper method.

Note: I have not tested this with passing a parameter.

```
    def add_workspace_to_session(workspace_id, url)
      session[:workspace_id] = workspace_id 
      url 
    end 

<%= button_to "Store Workspace", add_workspace_to_session(workspace_id, root_path), :method => :get %>
```

Comment: You might also want to pass the url in as a parameter so that the helper can be used for multiple urls.